# COALESCE(SUM(...),0) COALESCE(COUNT(...),0) not working in my code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get 0 instead of NULL with COALESCE but it seems like it doesn't work. Here's my code. You can see on the following picture what's the current result.
[image: result]

```
CREATE VIEW "PathToGraduation" (student, "totalCredits", "mandatoryLeft", "mathCredits", "researchCredits", "seminarCourses")
AS  SELECT idnr, "A".credits, "B"."mandatoryLeft", "C"."mathCredits", "D"."researchCredits", "E"."seminarCourses"
     FROM   "Students"
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (
               SELECT student, COALESCE(SUM(credits),0) AS credits
               FROM   "PassedCourses"
               GROUP BY student) AS "A"
               ON idnr = "A".student
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (
               SELECT UM.student, COALESCE(COUNT(UM.student),0) AS "mandatoryLeft"
               FROM  "Students" S, "UnreadMandatory" UM
               WHERE S.idnr = UM.student
               GROUP BY UM.student) AS "B"
               ON idnr = "B".student
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (
               SELECT PC.student, COALESCE(SUM(PC.credits),0) AS "mathCredits"
               FROM "PassedCourses" PC, "Classified" CL
               WHERE CL.course = PC.course AND CL.classification = 'math'
               GROUP BY "student") AS "C"
               ON idnr = "C".student
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (
               SELECT PC.student, COALESCE(SUM(PC.credits),0) AS "researchCredits"
               FROM "PassedCourses" PC, "Classified" CL
               WHERE CL.course = PC.course AND CL.classification = 'research'
               GROUP BY "student") AS "D"
               ON idnr = "D".student
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (
               SELECT PC.student, COALESCE(COUNT(PC.course),0) AS "seminarCourses"
               FROM "PassedCourses" PC, "Classified" CL
               WHERE CL.course = PC.course AND CL.classification = 'seminar'
               GROUP BY "student") AS "E"
               ON idnr = "E".student;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `COALESCE` expression will produce a non-null value(if it has one available) in each row produced by a query. But if the query *doesn't produce any rows at all*, there's no evaluation of the `COALESCE` expression.

Better to move them up into the outer/final `SELECT`, when the `LEFT JOIN`s have already had a chance to turn "no rows" into `NULL`s:

```
SELECT idnr, COALESCE("A".credits,0), COALESCE("B"."mandatoryLeft",0), 
             COALESCE("C"."mathCredits",0), COALESCE("D"."researchCredits",0), 
             COALESCE("E"."seminarCourses",0)
FROM   "Students"
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT student, SUM(credits) AS credits
         ...
```